# undefined keyword or key name: STRINGTABLE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have an old (circa 2006) Visual C++ project that I am modifying with Visual Studio 2010.  The project already had a resource file but did not have a "Version" resource in it.  So I added the "Version" resource without making any other changes to the project, and when I go to build it now I get the following error.

"Error  87  error RC2104: undefined keyword or key name: STRINGTABLE    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxres.rc"

I've done significant research trying to find an answer/solution without any luck.  I realize that the error message is saying it's not defined which is the problem but where is it defined?  Is there some other standard header file that has that defined?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's the [documentation for `STRINGTABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381050(v=vs.85).aspx). I suspect the actual error is in the line *before* the STRINGTABLE, preventing it from being recognized properly.

Comment: Didn't you forget to #include the file afxres.h?

Comment: @sergiol - No!  afxres.h is included in the .rc file.